# Infix strange behaviour

Tags: bugs, version-9, version-8

**Bug introduced in 7.0 and fixed in 10.0.0**

---

Maybe this is a bug or maybe Infix acts differently than the other functions.

The fact is that both:

```
TreeForm[Infix[f[x, a]]]
```

and

```
ToString[Infix[f[x, a]]]
```

crash the kernel. I use Mathematica 9.0 and maybe there are other cases that Infix behaves strangely.

Does anybody can explain why this happens ?

Comment: confirmed (9.000).

Comment: I confirm this behavior for *Mathematica* 8.0.4 under Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 4):

Hack workaround..

```
infix[f_] := Infix[f, "~" <> SymbolName[Head[f]] <> "~"];
ToString[infix[f[a, b, c]]]

-> "a~f~b~f~c"
```

Comment: Nice hack to get the String , but the TreeForm seems awkward. I am parsing some mma expressions and I would like to use the embedded functions as they are. So I am still puzzled... I would like to know the real reason why Infix fails above.

Comment: Also `ToString[
 Hold@(Infix[f[x, a], "~" <> SymbolName[Head[f[x, a]]] <> "~"])
 ]` crashes the kernel. Removing Hold or replacing with HoldAll works ok ...

Comment: note this also crashes: `OutputForm[Infix[f[a, b]]]` -- seems like a question for Wolfram support.

Comment: Sent to Wolfram support. I will update here when they send a feedback. Thanks @george2079

Answer (score 3):

This bug has been fixed as of version 10.0.0.

```
ToString[Infix[f[x, a]]]                                                
(* "x ~f~ a" *)

OutputForm[Infix[f[x, a]]]                                              
(* x ~f~ a *)
```